# how validate an email that allows specific number of dots before and after @ symbol

Tags: javascript, php

```
var val_em=document.add_indus_detail_form.txt_email.value;
var atpos=val_em.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=val_em.lastIndexOf(".");
if(val_em!='')
{
    if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=val_em.length)
      {
      alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
      return false;
      }
    }
```

i use this condition to check the email validation that user enters in the textbox how i can validate it like it allows 3 or 4 or any specific numbers of dot allow (ex abc.abc.abc.abc@abc.abc.com) before and after the @ but do not allow that  dots together (ex:  abc@abc...com). also do not allow the spaces in email how it will be have you any idea for this type of validation..

Comment: Check the email address on the server instead. In modern browsers you can use `<input type="email">` to help client-side validation as well.

Comment: Validate both on client and server side. If user has missed something, it is faster to have JS find it and report back. You will always validate on server regardless, but those unnecessary round trips will be cut back to a minimum.

Comment: ya but type="email" is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Validations in JavaScript are useless. The user can turn off JS or maybe you encounter a browser who cant even understand JS. This makes your page vulnerable to attacks. So NEVER use JS for validating user inputs.

What you want is RegEx or many if-conditions together with string-functions. My approach: Use a For-Loop, go through the string one by one, check the current character and the one after it. Like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++) {
    if(substr($string, 0, 1) == '.' {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a regex for this

```
function validateEmail(email){
    var emailReg = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-\s]+")|([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)|("[\w-\s]+")([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*))(@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][0-9]\.|1[0-9]{2}\.|[0-9]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
    var valid = emailReg.test(email);
    if(!valid) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

call the function `validateEmail` whenever you need....

Comment: three dots together or in total 3 dots ?

Comment: total 3 dot and it should not be together

Comment: ex: (1)xyz.xyz.xyz@com.com.com.com   allow  (1)xyz..@com..com notallow  (3)xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz@com.com or (4)xyz.xyz.xyz@com.com.com.com.com both  notallow because in #rd example it contains 4 dot before @  and in 4th example it contains 4dot after @. that i don't want to allow to user.please tell how it is posible.